# Proving $6+12+18+24+...+6n=3n(n+1)$ by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm learning prove by induction, but for some reason I just can't figure out the following example. I'll just work out the example and tell you guys where I'm stuck.

prove the following by induction $$6+12+18+24+...+6n=3n(n+1)$$

1. prove basis step (n=1).
   $$
   6 = 6*1 = 3*1(1+1) = 6
   $$
2. induction step, assume Sk is true, n = k
   $$
   6 + 12 + 18 + 24 + ... + 6k = 3k(k+1)
   $$
3. induction step n = k + 1

$$
6 + 12 + 18 + 24 + ... + 6(k+1) = 3(k+1)(k+2)
$$

4. bring Sk to both sides
   $$
   3k(k+1)+6(k+1) = 3(k+1)(k+2)
   $$
5. Simplify, I really have no idea how these equal eachother, what are the simplifying steps taken in this example? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to show $6+12+...+6k+6(k+1)=3(k+1)(k+2)$

Comment: Noting that your expression is $6\times (1+2+\cdots +n)$, do you already know how to evaluate  $1+2+\cdots +n$?

Comment: You are missing some parentheses:  should be $6(k+1)$ and $3(k+1)(k+2)$

Comment: You are missing parentheses. In your induction step, your last term should be 6(k+1). And the right side should be 3k(k+1) + 6(k+1)  (that's just the sum of terms up to k, plus the (k+1)st term). Now you would need to show that 3k(k+1)+6(k+1) = 3(k+1)(k+2)

Comment: It seems a lot of comments have popped up while I was typing my answer. I posted it anyway, and I hope it helps.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri you are absolutely right, I changed my answer.However I'm still stuck on the simplifying step..

Comment: You are stuck because the expression is still not correct. You should have $\color{red}6(k+1)$

Comment: You need to factor.: $3k(k+1)+6(k+1) = (3k+6)(k+1) = 3(k+2)(k+1) = 3(k+1)(k+2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps 3 and 4 don't look right. You can't just assume:

$6 + 12 + 18 + 24 + ... + 6k + 6(k+1) = 3(k+1)(k+2)$ and manipulate it.

You need to prove that from the inductive assumption. So you need to use the following:

$6 + 12 + 18 + 24 + ... + 6k = 3k(k+1)$ to try and prove:

$6 + 12 + 18 + 24 + ... + 6k + 6(k+1) = 3(k+1)(k+2)$

So what you can do is manipulate the left hand side, and show that it comes out to the right hand side

$6 + 12 + 18 + 24 + ... + 6k + 6(k+1)$

$=3k(k+1) + 6(k+1)$ (this is substitution from our inductive assumption)

$=(3k+6)(k+1)$

$=3(k+2)(k+1)$

$=3(k+1)(k+2)$

So that shows the left hand side equals the right hand side. And that completes the proof.

Comment: I'm struggling so hard with the `= (3k+6)(k+1)`, how do you go from a `+` to a '*', probably a very stupid question but I just can't figure it out, all the other steps are very clear!

Comment: Do you know how to go from $(3k+6)(k+1)$ to $3k(k+1)+6(k+1)$? We're just using the distributive property of multiplication in reverse. The distributive property is $(a+b)c = ac+bc$. In our case $a=3k$, $b=6$ and $c=k+1$. I highly recommend doing some algebra factoring and simplification exercises. You can find tons online. You really want that stuff to become second nature by doing lots of exercises.

Comment: Ahhhh thank god thanks for taking the time to fully work out the exercise! After an hour I finally understand it. I will for sure be doing some extra exercises on that topic.

Comment: No problem! You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I'll write out how I would prove this.

Prove $$6 + 12 + \cdots + 6n = 3n(n + 1).$$

*Proof*. We will first prove that $$1 + 2 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \tag{1}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Note that $$1 = \frac{1(1+1)}{2}.$$ Suppose $(1)$ holds when $n = k.$ If that is the case, then $$1 + 2 + \cdots + k = \frac{k(k + 1)}{2}. \tag{2}$$ We now add $k + 1$ to both sides to $(2)$ to get $$1 + 2 + \cdots + k + k + 1 = \frac{k(k + 1)}{2} + k + 1. \tag{3}$$ Doing some algebra on the right hand side of $(3),$ we see that $$\frac{k(k + 1)}{2} + k + 1 = \frac{k(k+1) + 2(k + 1)}{2} = \frac{(k + 1)(k + 2)}{2},$$ which implies that we have proved that $(1)$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ We now multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $6$ to get $$6 + 12 + \cdots + 6n = 3n(n + 1).$$

Comment: What is the reason that you chose to go for the $$n(n+1)/2$$ approach?

Comment: @Jordy Because I saw that it was the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers, multiplied by $6.$ In fact, using my proof you can instantly generalize this to $$k + 2k + 3k + \cdots + nk = \frac{nk(n + 1)}{2}.$$ Usually, if you are being asked to prove a specific case of a general case, and you can prove the general case easily, then I almost always recommend to prove the general case and then demonstrate that it is true for the specific case (since it has to be).

EDIT: To clarify, “easily” would imply that it is just as difficult, or even less difficult as the specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do the inductive step in this specific case:

*Inductive hypothesis*: for some $k$, we have $\:6 + 12 + 18 + 24 + ... + 6k = 3k(k+1)$.

We have to deduce that $\:6 + 12 + 18 + 24 + ... + 6(k+1) = 3(k+1)(k+2)$.

Now, we can group the terms in the l.h.s. and use the inductive hypothesis:
$$(6 + 12 + 18 + 24 + ... + 6k)+6(k+1) = 3k(k+1)+6(k+1)=3(k+1)(k+2).$$

Comment: Hmm okay, the simplifying steps are kind of magical to me, I don't understand how ````3k(k+1)+6(k+1)(k+2) = 3(k+1)(k+2)``` I think that's where I mainly get stuck at. How would you call these steps? Simplifying? If that's the mathematical term for it, I'll have to watch some videos about it to better understand.

Comment: It's factoring $3k(k+1)+6(k+1)$ you can group the terms together. $(3k+6)(k+1)$. Now you factor out the 3. $3(k+2)(k+1)$. Then you can rearrange $3(k+1)(k+2)$.

Comment: @Jordy: It's quite simple: in each term, I factor out $3(k+1)$. So there remains the factor $k$ in the first term, and the factor $2$ in the second.

Answer (score 0):

$6+12+18+24+\dots+6n=6(1+2+3+4+\dots+n)=6n(n+1)/2=3n(n+1)$.

The key is the well-known Gauß sum.  He did it as a school boy by pairing the first and last term, second and second to last, etc...